# Java , variable cant be read after If selection

Tags: java

I have a problem here , I want to print the `hp2` but it says error. How can I solve this problem? How can I print that `hp2` without an error? Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lala {

    public static void main (String []args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int hp=100;
        int hp1;
        int go=10;  
        int a;

        hp1=hp-go;
        System.out.println(hp1);
        a=scan.nextInt();

        int hp2;
        if (a==1) {
            hp2=hp1-10;
        } else {}

        System.out.println(hp2);
}
}
```

Comment: Give it a default value when you declare it, before the if, `int hp2 = 0;` Or give it a value in the `else` block.

Comment: What error are you getting. Also @SotiriosDelimanolis Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @handuel So others can get points. I don't like giving formal answers to easy questions.

Comment: Imagine what would happen in your code if `a` doesn't equal `1`. You would be trying to print out a variable that cannot have a value at that point.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the local variable. If you don't initialize the local variable then you get compile time error.

```
int hp1 = 0;
int hp2 = 0;
int a = 0;
```

Initialize all local variable and the hp1 because if condition become false then this variable become uninitialize and bottom you are printing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test

{

public static void main (String []args)

{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int hp=100;

    int hp1;

    int go=10;  

        int a;

    hp1=hp-go;

    System.out.println(hp1);

    a=scan.nextInt();

    int hp2 = 0;

    if (a==1)

    {

        hp2=hp1-10;

    }

    else

    {

    }

    System.out.println(hp2);

}
    }
```

Comment: What's with the double spacing?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize each and every variable before u use it in any of the part of the application

Answer (score 0):

Initialize each of the variables. At least give each variable that isn't currently assigned a value a 0.